# Iterating every other AJAX object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JSON encoded AJAX object array and I need to iterate every other one. I'm new to jQuery and JS and are unsure how to do this. I need the numbers to be the option value and the string name as the object name.

The AJAX object (note although in this example the numerals are in order they might not be because the integers are an auto_id from a database and numbers might be skipped or out of order:

```
{"data":["1","chicken","2","beef","3","fish","4","pork","5","turkey","6","lamb","7","vennison","8","duck"],"error":false}
```

I tried the following code below which doesn't work. I tried to do a search for this answer but couldn't find it. TIA. Currently, newOption is returning "undefined".

```
 $.each(data.data, function(i,s){
     var count=s[i];
     var newOption = s[i+1];           
     output += '<option value="' + count + '">' + newOption + '</option>';
     i++;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop, but increment the counter by 2 each loop:

```
var data = {"data":["1","chicken","2","beef","3","fish","4","pork","5","turkey","6","lamb","7","vennison","8","duck"],"error":false}

var output = '';

for(i = 0; i < data.data.length; i+=2) {
  output += '<option value="' + data.data[i] + '">' + data.data[i+1] + '</option>';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/go98npym/

Answer (score 1):

Can you use an `if` statement with modulus? And then initialize your `count` outside the loop.

```
var count = 0;
$.each(data.data, function(i,element){
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    count++;
    output += '<option value="' + count + '">' + element + '</option>';
  }
  i++;
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt. The numbers may not be in order because they are an auto_id from a database so I need to get them from the array object. I'm getting newOption="undefined" on the web page. I believe I'm not referencing the object properly with the index.

Comment: You are correct about `newOption="undefined"`. Your `s` variable is the actual element itself. Check my updated code.

Comment: I don't believe I saw anything about them being out of order the first time.

Comment: Is your goal to have them back in order at the end? You didn't mention anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

When Iterating over a Array using jQuery.each the first param is index and the second one is value in the index itself.

Instead of using jQuery use plain javascript.

try the following:

```
var d = data.data;
var output = "";

for (var i = 0 ; i< d.length; i=i+2) {
  var count = d[i];
  var newOption = d[i+1];
  output += "<option value='"+count+"'>"+newOption+"</option>";
}
```